# Is it possible to run Xcode programs in Swift playgrounds?

Tags: swift, ipad

Before I begin programming Swift with Xcode, is it possible for you to somehow send the program to Swift playgrounds on an iPad?

Comment: iPad playground for beginners. For developing app you can use Xcode playground on Mac

Comment: But what if I developed the app, but I want to play it on Swift playgrounds?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [Swift Playgrounds developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/swift-playgrounds/):

> Playgrounds were first introduced as a way to experiment with your
>   code in Xcode, and now with Swift Playgrounds you can easily use those
>   same playgrounds on iPad. iCloud Drive seamlessly shares your Mac
>   playgrounds with your iPad, and changes you make on either device are
>   immediately updated.

So if your questions is to be interpreted strictly, then no, you can't run "Xcode programs", but you should be able to use playgrounds developed in Xcode.